# How to find state abbreviation in array from get value

Tags: javascript, arrays, var, abbreviation

I am trying to get the state abbreviation from a client IP address.

I have used the API from IPInfo.org to return the state from an IP address and that has worked fine like this:

```
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
$state = response.region;
}, "jsonp");
```

I have seen many state name to abbreviation lists like this online (https://gist.github.com/mshafrir/2646763):

```
{
'Alabama': 'AL',
'Alaska': 'AK',
'American Samoa': 'AS',
'Arizona': 'AZ',
'Arkansas': 'AR',
'California': 'CA',
'Colorado': 'CO',
'Connecticut': 'CT',
'Delaware': 'DE',
'District Of Columbia': 'DC',
'Federated States Of Micronesia': 'FM',
'Florida': 'FL',
'Georgia': 'GA',
'Guam': 'GU',
'Hawaii': 'HI',
'Idaho': 'ID',
'Illinois': 'IL',
'Indiana': 'IN',
'Iowa': 'IA',
'Kansas': 'KS',
'Kentucky': 'KY',
'Louisiana': 'LA',
'Maine': 'ME',
'Marshall Islands': 'MH',
'Maryland': 'MD',
'Massachusetts': 'MA',
'Michigan': 'MI',
'Minnesota': 'MN',
'Mississippi': 'MS',
'Missouri': 'MO',
'Montana': 'MT',
'Nebraska': 'NE',
'Nevada': 'NV',
'New Hampshire': 'NH',
'New Jersey': 'NJ',
'New Mexico': 'NM',
'New York': 'NY',
'North Carolina': 'NC',
'North Dakota': 'ND',
'Northern Mariana Islands': 'MP',
'Ohio': 'OH',
'Oklahoma': 'OK',
'Oregon': 'OR',
'Palau': 'PW',
'Pennsylvania': 'PA',
'Puerto Rico': 'PR',
'Rhode Island': 'RI',
'South Carolina': 'SC',
'South Dakota': 'SD',
'Tennessee': 'TN',
'Texas': 'TX',
'Utah': 'UT',
'Vermont': 'VT',
'Virgin Islands': 'VI',
'Virginia': 'VA',
'Washington': 'WA',
'West Virginia': 'WV',
'Wisconsin': 'WI',
'Wyoming': 'WY'
}
```

but I am not sure of how to actually take the output from the one function and use it in this array to output the correct abbreviation.

How is this done?
Thanks you in advance!

Comment: Your input will be the state name and output will be the abbr.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple. You can access properties of JSON object in two ways.

1. Access using bracket notation
2. Access using dot ('.') notation (recommended)

I've created a function called `getStateAbbr` which take state name from `ipinfo.io` and using bracket notation, you get corresponding value. Why did I use bracket notation because it can have dynamic values.

If you try `.` nation then you will get `undefined`.

```js
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
  var state = response.region;
  getStateAbbr(state);
}, "jsonp");

var states = {
  'Alabama': 'AL',
  'Alaska': 'AK',
  'American Samoa': 'AS',
  'Arizona': 'AZ',
  'Arkansas': 'AR',
  'California': 'CA',
  'Colorado': 'CO',
  'Connecticut': 'CT',
  'Delaware': 'DE',
  'District Of Columbia': 'DC',
  'Federated States Of Micronesia': 'FM',
  'Florida': 'FL',
  'Georgia': 'GA',
  'Guam': 'GU',
  'Hawaii': 'HI',
  'Idaho': 'ID',
  'Illinois': 'IL',
  'Indiana': 'IN',
  'Iowa': 'IA',
  'Kansas': 'KS',
  'Kentucky': 'KY',
  'Louisiana': 'LA',
  'Maine': 'ME',
  'Marshall Islands': 'MH',
  'Maryland': 'MD',
  'Massachusetts': 'MA',
  'Michigan': 'MI',
  'Minnesota': 'MN',
  'Mississippi': 'MS',
  'Missouri': 'MO',
  'Montana': 'MT',
  'Nebraska': 'NE',
  'Nevada': 'NV',
  'New Hampshire': 'NH',
  'New Jersey': 'NJ',
  'New Mexico': 'NM',
  'New York': 'NY',
  'North Carolina': 'NC',
  'North Dakota': 'ND',
  'Northern Mariana Islands': 'MP',
  'Ohio': 'OH',
  'Oklahoma': 'OK',
  'Oregon': 'OR',
  'Palau': 'PW',
  'Pennsylvania': 'PA',
  'Puerto Rico': 'PR',
  'Rhode Island': 'RI',
  'South Carolina': 'SC',
  'South Dakota': 'SD',
  'Tennessee': 'TN',
  'Texas': 'TX',
  'Utah': 'UT',
  'Vermont': 'VT',
  'Virgin Islands': 'VI',
  'Virginia': 'VA',
  'Washington': 'WA',
  'West Virginia': 'WV',
  'Wisconsin': 'WI',
  'Wyoming': 'WY'
}

function getStateAbbr(name) {
  alert(states[name]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the property via bracket-notation/subscript:

```
var stateName = response.region;
var stateAbbreviation = abbreviations[stateName];
```